# Macros to compare shop name and Invoice Number between two sheets and highlight matches

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi Guys I am not sure if the code for this is already given I tried similar questions but I didnt find an appropriate solution so I am asking this here

"Note: I use Office 2010 only"

**The Problem:**

I have two sheets in excel with the entries like Tin No, Customer Name, Invoice Number, Cost, Tax, Value before Tax, Value after-tax, etc., Now I have to compare both the Customer Name and Invoice Number in both sheets and return the value or highlight the results.

**The Situation**
(Sheet 1)

| Customer Name | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- |
| Carpenter | 101 |
| Painter | 102 |
| Courier | 103 |
| Welder | 104 |
| Painter | 105 |
| Courier | 106 |
| Welder | 107 |

(Sheet 2)

| Customer Name | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- |
| Carpenter | 101 |
| Courier | 103 |
| Welder | 104 |
| Painter | 105 |
| Welder | 107 |

In Sheet 2 Invoice numbers 102 and 106 are missing I want that Highlighted in a separate column or in the same sheet with a different color.

If it is still not clear please let me know.

Comment: Showing your attempt (using `vba` or `conditional formatting`) and adding screenshots of the worksheets (showing a practical case) would make it an acceptable question. You can [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67075110/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with formula to cross-check both files.

First sheet:

| Customer Name (A1) | Invoice Number (B1) | Key (C1) | Find_Missing - formula - (D1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carpenter (A2) | 101 (B2) | =A2&B2 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet2!C:C;Match(A2&B2;Sheet2!C:C;0));"Not Found") |
| Painter (A3) | 102 (B3) | =A3&B3 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet2!C:C;Match(A3&B3;Sheet2!C:C;0));"Not Found") |
| Courier (A4) | 103 (B4) | =A4&B4 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet2!C:C;Match(A4&B4;Sheet2!C:C;0));"Not Found") |

Second sheet:

| Customer Name (A1) | Invoice Number (B1) | Key (C1) | Find_Missing - formula - (D1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carpenter (A2) | 101 (B2) | =A2&B2 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet1!C:C;Match(A2&B2;Sheet1!C:C;0));"Not Found") |
| Courier (A3) | 103 (B3) | =A3&B3 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet1!C:C;Match(A3&B3;Sheet1!C:C;0));"Not Found") |
| Welder (A4) | 104 (B4) | =A4&B4 | =Iferror(Index(Sheet1!C:C;Match(A4&B4;Sheet1!C:C;0));"Not Found") |